# Jenkins pipeline should is removing container on remote daemon after deployment, i want to keep it running

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, daemon

I am trying to build deploy my code using jenkins pipeline and also using remote docker daemon for deployment. 
everything is working but jenkins pipeline is stoping and removing all containers once pipeline script ends. server is coming up just for 10 seconds after that container stops and removed.

```
   stage {
        steps {
                 script {
                           docker.withServer('tcp://10.10.10.10:2375') {
                           docker.withRegistry('https://registry.my.com/','jenkins-registry') {
                           docker.image('registry.my.com/image-my/my:latest').withRun(' -p 9090:80 -i -t --name harpal ') {
                                                         sh 'docker ps -a'
                                    }
                            }
                       }
               }
        }
```

output

```
[Flights-Docker-POC] Running shell script
+ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                  NAMES
6a4c5094a8d2        registry.my.com/image-my/my:latest   "/usr/bin/supervisord"   6 hours ago         Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:9090->80/tcp   harpal
[Pipeline] sh
[Flights-Docker-POC] Running shell script
+ docker stop 6a4c5094a8d22179b364ee2d3b97e998a2c13e8b136c55816c0d8f838c17248b
6a4c5094a8d22179b364ee2d3b97e998a2c13e8b136c55816c0d8f838c17248b
+ docker rm -f 6a4c5094a8d22179b364ee2d3b97e998a2c13e8b136c55816c0d8f838c17248b
6a4c5094a8d22179b364ee2d3b97e998a2c13e8b136c55816c0d8f838c17248b
```

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile here? What is the CMD or ENTRYPOINT in your docker container? Is there a possibility it would exit after 10 secs?

Comment: i am not deploying using Dockerfile, i m using Jenkins pipeline script. to to deploy. usign Dockerfile just to build Docker image. did you mean there may some issue with my docker image? or you want my complete Jenkins pipeline script.

Comment: yes i meant there might be something with your docker image

Comment: my CMD is starting using supervisord.conf,and below is config inside is,


[supervisord]
nodaemon=true


[program:hostsEntry]
command=sh -c "cat /tmp/hosts>>/etc/hosts"
autorestart=false
startretries = 0

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'
autorestart=true

[program:tomcat]
command=/opt/tomcat/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh run
autorestart=true

Answer (score 1):

```
got the answer for it.it wasn't issue related to entry point in my image
was suppose to use image.run() method instead of withRun(), withRun() method internally calls run() method and stops container in finally block of its implementation. 

 public <V> V withRun(String args = '', Closure<V> body) {
            docker.node {
                Container c = run(args)
                try {
                    body.call(c)
                } finally {
                    c.stop()
                }
            }
        }
btw thank you guys for help.

script was supposed to be like.

       stage {
            steps {
                     script {
                               docker.withServer('tcp://10.10.10.10:2375') {
                               docker.withRegistry('https://registry.my.com/','jenkins-registry') {
                               docker.image('registry.my.com/image-my/my:latest').run(' -p 9090:80 -i -t --name harpal ') 

    }
                           }
                   }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to keep it alive using that Docker plugin Groovy class, it's intended to remove the container after the run.

If you're just trying to launch Docker containers from Jenkins, just use shell commands to do a

```
sh 'docker run -p 9090:80 -i -t --name harpal registry.my.com/image-my/my:latest '
```

If you're trying to keep a container alive to debug it and look around I usually add

```
sh 'sleep 30m'
```

Then go to the Docker machine and take a look around the container with

```
docker exec -it <ContainerID> bash
```

Comment: if i put 'sleep 30m', my jenkins project is keep on running, i want my pipeline to exit gracefully. and later on use the server started by this projects for other usage

Comment: Then use my first suggestion of launching the docker container with docker run, instead of using the docker plugin's groovy class. The pipeline job will finish and the container will still be alive

Comment: You could also try adding -d or --detach in your withRun(), it might stay alive that way too.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but when using your first suggestion it exits from container. Exited (1) 31 seconds ago. and -d is already added but pipeline. and when using  --detach also nothing changes